# TDA 2050 Single Application Circuit

Tags: audio, amplifier

[image: Circuit Picture]

I have constructed an Audio Amplifier using TDA 2050 single supply but I am having difficulty understanding the circuit.

It contains the TDA 2050, (32W hifi audio Amplifier) with Vs = +15 V.

Can anyone please help explain the detailed functionality of this circuit, such as

1- Why do we need voltage divider (R1 and R2)? Can't we use direct Vs as +7.5 V and remove R1?

2- How do we calculate its gain ? (I got around 33, is that right?)

3- How do we calculate its cut-off frequency? (upper and lower)? (I got 3.2883 Hz?)

4- Why there are different types of capacitors?

5- Can we change non-electrolytic with electrolytic capacitors and vice versa?

7- What is the purpose of C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6 and C7?

8- What happens if we remove C4 ?

9- What happens if we remove C6 ?

10- Do we need to change the capacitance of capacitors if we increase/decrease Vs?

11- What is the main purpose of C5? We used that capacitor in breadboard but not in PCB.

Answer (score 3):

That's a lot of questions in one, but here goes.

1) R1,R2 generate Vs/2. If you have a 7.5V supply and Vs is regulated to 15 then you can eliminate them; however Vs/2 is better if Vs can vary.

2) If you got gain around 33 you're doing it about right.

3) Upper cutoff frequency is not determined by any of these components; the datasheet should show it for different gains. Lower : I think you calculated C1/R3. There are two other LF cutoffs : C4/R4 and C7/RL; these look like higher frequencies.

4) For different purposes. Ceramic capacitors are good for low values, electrolytic for high values. And metal film caps are highly accurate and stable, (and some people say they sound better) but I don't see any of them here. Elecrolytics have one big limitation : they are polarised - they should be used with a DC voltage across them, and they must be connected right way round.

5) Generally, no. You can't usually find non-electrolytic caps large enough (though if you can, at the right voltage rating, you can sometimes substitute).
And connecting electrolytic caps in unbiased positions or where voltage might be reversed, is usually a bad idea.

6) no question 6?

7) ah, Q7 makes up for it...
C1 : Coupling. DC block between "In" voltage and pin 1
C2 : Decoupling. Remove noise on Vs/2
C3 : Decoupling. Reduce noise on Vs, smooth out supply voltage
C4 : Filtering. Reduce DC gain to 1.
C5 : Decoupling. Remove HF noise on Vs, improve stability, eliminate HF oscillation.
C6 : Zobel network (good search term). Eliminate HF oscillation.
C7 : Coupling. DC block between "Out" and speaker. Avoids blowing up speaker.

8) Gain = 33 down to DC. (ASSUMING you reconnect R4) Translates e.g. 10mv input offset to 330mv DC offset at output. Not so serious in this configuration because of C7, starting to eat into voltage swing and thus output power. In configurations with +/-7.5V and no C7, applies DC to loudspeaker : bad.

9) If you're lucky, nothing. Otherwise : HF oscillation, horrible whistling noises, distortion, overheating IC, and interference with radio transmissions.

10) Not necessarily. But if that increases the current output, then yes. But in my opinion, C3 and C7 are too small to call this a hi-fi amplifier, 4700uf might be a better choice. (Can you hear the difference? :-)

11) See Q7. But what happens if you omit it? 
If you're lucky, nothing - while C3 is fresh and new. But after a few months when it starts to age, possibly: HF oscillation - see Q9.

Answer (score 0):

I have just completed construction of a bridge TDA2050 amplifier which is capable of outputting 130 Watt RMS into an 8 ohm load; TDA2050 has a maximum 5 A output current before current limiting occurs.

This is a fantastic power amplifier with lovely clear sound quality in operation.  However, I found that there is a very great need to mount two power-supply decoupling ceramic 100 nF capacitors very spatially close to the device mounted on a heatsink, otherwise it has a tendency to oscillate at high RF frequencies.  This is especially important if you are using long leads from the PCB to the device on the heatsink.

Note that a bridge configuration with two paralleled TDA2050 on each side of the bridge could be made to deliver 10 Amps peak, allowing circa 250 Watt RMS amplifier into 4 ohm load to be realized at a very modest cost.

Kind regards

Dr Timothy Norris